# show the input fields of a form only if compiled

Tags: php

I'm sorry for my english.

I'm trying to show in a page result.php the input fields filled in a form.
Since I have so many inputs (each with a different name) I would like to avoid creating an if statement for each input. The only solution I found is the following:

```
<?php if ($dim_100x100) {
echo "<div class=''><div class=''><div class=''><span class=''>100x100</span></div><input type='number' class='' value='$dim_100x100' readonly='' /></div></div>";} ?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
 <head> 
.....
 </head>
<body>
<form id="calcolo_canali" action="result.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" target="_blank">
    .....

<input name="dim_100x100" type="number" class="" value="<?php if (isset($dim_100x100)) {echo $dim_100x100;}  ?>">
    ..... other many inputs ....
<div class="">
        <button class="" type="submit" name="add" value="ADD">send</button>
    </div>
</form>
    <footer class="">
        .....
    </footer>
    <script src="">
        .....
    </script>
```

result.php

```
<?php error_reporting(0); 
if (isset($_POST['dim_100x100'])) {    
 $dim_100x100 = $_POST['dim_100x100']; 
} ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
.....
</head>
<body>
<td>
 ................ here I want to show only the compiled fields ....
</td>
................ my bad solution (?):
<?php
if ($dim_100x100) {
    echo "<div class=''><div class=''><div class=''><span class=''>100x100</span></div><input type='number' class='' value='$dim_100x100' readonly='' /></div></div>";
}
?>
<footer class=""> ..... </footer>
</div>
<script src=""></script>
</body></html>
```

I searched the site for different solutions but I can't get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

A classic solution would be

```
<?php if ($dim_100x100): ?>
    <div class=''>
        <div class=''>
            <div class=''>
                <span class=''>100x100</span>
            </div>
            <input type='number' class='' value='<?= $dim_100x100 ?>' readonly=''/></div>
    </div>";
<?php endif; ?>
```

If your server does not support `<?=` tag could you replace it with `<?php echo ... ?>`

Comment: thanks for answer MyLibary. 
Yes. this solution is valid for checking only one input. For all the other inputs I have to insert many other if statements. there is no cycle that checks all the inputs and shows them only if they are filled out?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `$_POST` and output whichever fields have been filled.

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
    if ($value) {
        echo "Do what you need to with $name and $value";
    }
}
```

`$name` will be `dim_100x100` etc.

If other things are in `$_POST` that you don't want to see, there are various possibilities to exclude them from the output, including:

- Add another conditional inside the loop to compare the field name to an array of names you define

  ```
  if ($value && in_array($name, $array_of_field_names_you_want_to_output) { ...
  ```
- Group the form inputs you want to output in an array in `$_POST` by naming them using array syntax

  ```
  <input type="number" name="output-group[dim_100x100]" >
  ```

Comment: oh wow thank you. here we are !!! I only have one little problem: it also prints "add" which is the value of the submit button. how can i do to exclude it? Look at code: https://codepen.io/Alighieri/pen/gOOzwgB

Comment: The second part of my answer was referring to that kind of problem, but that may be overkill for this situation. If the only extra thing in $_POST is the submit button, I'd suggest just removing its name attribute. Unless you're specifically doing something with the submit button value, you don't need to submit that control with the rest of the form inputs.

Comment: in fact I removed the name of the send button. Thanks, you were so helpful